# Finding an element in list of list, in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

I am trying to find an element in a list of lists; in particular, if a specific city can be found in a country.

I have states: `List[State]` and cities: `List[City]`, which means that countries are represented as `List[List[City]]`.

I wrote this piece of code, but it seems that I am facing a problem. This is the snippet:

```
case class city (
  name: String, 
  CodePostal: Double, 
  visit: Boolean
)


def belongToCountry(p: city): Boolean =
  countries.flatten.foreach {
    case p => return true 
    case _ => return false
  }

def belongToCountry(p: city): Boolean =
  countries.foreach(s => s.city.contains(p))
```

Comment: should this be a `country` instead of `countries`?

Comment: I'd think the signature of the the function should be `def belongToCountry(country: List[List[City]], p: City): Boolean`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `contains` instead of `foreach`:

```
def belongToCountry(p: city): Boolean =
  countries.exists(s => s.contains(p))
```

The idea is: `city` belongs to collection of `countries` if collection of `countries` `contains` `country` that `contains` this `city`.

Alternatively you could get all cities from collection of countries and then check if the result contains this `city`:

```
def belongToCountry(p: city): Boolean =
  countries.view.flatten.exists{_ == p}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more verbose solution with `for` expression would be

```
def belongToCountry(city: city): Boolean = {

  val checkIterator: Iterator[Boolean] = for {
    country <- countries.toIterator
    cityName <- country
    if (city.name == cityName)
  } yield true

  checkIterator.hasNext match {
    case true => checkIterator.next()
    case false => false
  }
}
```